# Get reference of function inside function for usage in prototype/creation function

Tags: python

I have two nested functions: The outer creates a creation method / prototype, the inner will create a concrete example of that prototype:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

def make_prototype(proto_name):
    def make_example(example_name):
        return Example(proto_name + ' ' + example_name)
    return make_example

proto = make_prototype('Prototype 1')
ex1 = proto('Example 1')
```

Now, I'd like to remember the used creation function in the `Example`. I did it the following way:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, str, proto):
        self.str = str
        self.proto = proto

def make_prototype(proto_name):
    class make_example:
        def __call__(self, example_name):
            return Example(proto_name + ' ' + example_name, self)
    return make_example()

proto = make_prototype('Prototype 1')
ex1 = proto('Example 1')
ex2 = ex1.proto('Example 2')
```

I think that's a relatively elegant and understandable solution. BUT would there be a way to do it without the nested `class make_example`? Would there be a way to do it like in the first version and getting a reference to the function `make_example` directly inside `make_example`? Something like:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, str, proto):
        self.str = str
        self.proto = proto

def make_prototype(proto_name):
    def make_example(example_name):
        return Example(proto_name + ' ' + example_name, REFERENCE TO THIS FUNC)
    return make_example

proto = make_prototype('Prototype 1')
ex1 = proto('Example 1')
ex2 = ex1.proto('Example 2')
```

Comment: `return Example(proto_name + ' ' + example_name,make_example)` ?

Comment: @dnit13: Works! Not the first time I didn't try the simplest thing before asking. Sometimes Python is suprisingly smooth :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__call__` class method. Your example would look like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, str, proto):
        self.str = str
        self.proto = proto

class MakePrototype():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, proto_name):
        return Example(proto_name, self)



proto = MakePrototype('Prototype 1')
ex1 = proto('Example 1')
ex2 = ex1.proto('Example 2')
```

Comment: I see no essential differnce to what I already did, and it does particularly not answer the question.

Comment: U don't have nested functions or classes. Additionally, it looks flatter, nested functions always confuse me, but it is subjective feeling :)